# Wordpress Contents of sidebar being repeated

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recreated a new sidebar for this site and you can see it working perfecty on this page - http://dev.thehrdirector.com/features/

However, if you click on Archives (http://dev.thehrdirector.com/features/archive/) you'll see that the contents of the sidebar are being repeated over and over.  I'm absolutely stumped as both pages are using the same code.  Can anyone help me?

This is the code for the archive page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main role="main" id="article-new">
    <section id="content" class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-col floatleft">
            <div class="title-bar uppercase white brandon">
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>?post_type=features" title="<?php _e('Syndicate this site using RSS'); ?>" class="floatleft"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/rss-feed.png" alt="RSS Feed" title="RSS Feed" /></a>
                <h1 class="floatleft"><?php _e( 'Features', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>
                <div class="floatright">
                    More Articles: <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/features" class="white">Latest</a> <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/features-popular" class="white">Popular</a> <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'features' ); ?>" class="white active">Archives</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php $taxonomy = 'features_categories';
                $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
                if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            ?>
                <ul class="archives freight">
                    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>

        <div class="right-col floatright">
            <?php get_sidebar('article'); ?>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

and this is the code for the sidebar:

```
<aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
<?php 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        if( have_rows('article_sidebar_content', 'option') ): 

            while ( have_rows('article_sidebar_content', 'option') ) : the_row();

            // LATEST NEWS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'latest_news' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // ADVERTS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'ads' )
                get_template_part('partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // LATEST SENIOR HR JOBS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'latest_senior_hr_jobs' )
                get_template_part('partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // FEATURES
            if( get_row_layout() == 'features' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // LATEST ROUNDTABLE REPORT
            //LATEST HR DIRECTOR INTERVIEW
            //LEGAL UPDATES
            //BLOG          
            if( get_row_layout() == 'misc' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            endwhile; 
        endif; 

    endwhile; endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You Test wp_reset_query() in sidebar.

```
<?php 
query_post('post_type=post');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        if( have_rows('article_sidebar_content', 'option') ): 

            while ( have_rows('article_sidebar_content', 'option') ) : the_row();

            // LATEST NEWS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'latest_news' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // ADVERTS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'ads' )
                get_template_part('partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // LATEST SENIOR HR JOBS
            if( get_row_layout() == 'latest_senior_hr_jobs' )
                get_template_part('partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // FEATURES
            if( get_row_layout() == 'features' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            // LATEST ROUNDTABLE REPORT
            //LATEST HR DIRECTOR INTERVIEW
            //LEGAL UPDATES
            //BLOG          
            if( get_row_layout() == 'misc' )
                get_template_part( 'partials/'. get_row_layout() );

            endwhile; 
        endif; 

    endwhile; endif; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```